# Jquery validation with zip codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I have a program that allows a user to enter a zip code to generate a google map. I want to make sure that the zip code is valid. To do so I am using the jquery validate method. Here is how my code looks:

```
$('#zipInput').validator({
    format: 'zipUS',
    invalidEmpty: true,
    correct: function () {
       //Code for correct
    },
    error: function() {
      //Error code here
    }
});
```

The problem is that this is not working for me. I get the error `$('#zipInput').validator if not a function`. I have been looking for examples of the validate method online and I used this [link](http://igorgladkov.com/resources/demos/jquery.validator/demos/zip_us_validation.html) to build my code. I have added `jquery.validate.js` to my web page as well (issue with incorrect sources maybe?) Any suggestions or examples that I could look at to help figure out my issue?

**EDIT:** Here is all of the scripts I use in order:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script src="mwheelIntent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Must we assume that the app should not work outside the United States?

Comment: I guess the app could work outside of the united states, but it is for a store located in the US. The zip code is used to generate a map of nearby stores. If the zip code is valid but not in the US (something like 00000 maybe) that is fine. I just need to make a zip has been entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do at least two things:

1. Load jQuery itself before the plugin.
2. Enclose your code in a `jQuery.ready()` construct.

If you are already doing so, please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Do I still have to use `jQuery.ready()` if the validate will be used after the page has loaded? The zip code form is located in a dialog that will be brought up after a button is clicked

Comment: @SsRide360 - I'll put it in different words: `$('#zipInput')` will not find #zipInput unless it exists when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a call to the validator code you've written inside the function which you are using to call the dialog. This is if the validator code is in the dialog which you are loading.

Another idea is to put the validator code inside the jquery.ready function in the form from which you load the dialog, but this will add some redundant code to that page.

Comment: Moving where the call was still caused errors. If I use `.validate` instead of `.validator` no initial errors are thrown, but after I try to type in a zip code i get the error `.validator is undefined`